# how to remove the child node in js

Tags: javascript, removechild

i have one parent node name orgdiv and one child node name newdiv. I am trying to remove the child node but its not working here is the code.

```
function ajxsrch(str) {
    if (str.length != 0) {
        if (count == 0) {
            var newdiv = document.createElement('DIV');
            newdiv.className = "newsearch";
            var orgdiv = document.getElementById("search");
            orgdiv.appendChild(newdiv);
            count = 1;
            alert("firstif");
        } else alert("first if else");
    } else {
        alert(str);
        count = 0;
        alert(count);
        newdiv.orgdiv.removeChild(newdiv);
    }
}
```

Comment: Define "it's not working." What is it doing? What is it *not* doing? What *should* it be doing? Are there any errors reported in the JavaScript console (have you looked at your browser's JavaScript console)? Have you checked the syntax (using [JS Lint](http://jslint.com/), for example?

Comment: What is `newdiv.orgdiv`?

Comment: its not working means the third last lines in which i tried to remove the child is not doing its work

Comment: newdiv is child div nd orgdiv is parrent div

Comment: In your browser run that code. Then press 'F12' and look at the error(s).

Comment: But at `newdiv.orgdiv.removeChild(newdiv);` `newdiv` is `undefined` and if you look in the `console` you will see an error, something like `TypeError: Cannot read property 'orgdiv' of undefined `

Comment: @Xotic750 var newdiv = document.createElement('DIV'); this lines define the newdiv

Comment: And what does it say in the `console`?

Comment: yes it is giving error  "can not convert 'newdiv' to object

Comment: So you need to store a reference to `newdiv` and `orgdiv` or look those references up (`document.getElementById` or something similar) when entering that scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with your approach, and your JavaScript console will typically assist in debugging most of these.

First of all, consider the objects `newdiv` and `orgdiv`. Inside your `else` block, you reference both of these, but they are not declared or initialized anywhere. There is a declaration in your `if` block, but of course that doesn't get run the second time this method is called. When the `else` block is executing, the `if` block is ignored altogether.

So you need to correct your object references:

```
function ajxsrch(str) {
    var orgdiv = document.getElementById("search");
    var newdiv = document.getElementById("newDivId"); // assuming div has an ID
    ...
```

Then of course, in your `if` block, you will initialize `newdiv` correctly since it doesn't exist yet.

```
newdiv = document.createElement('DIV');
newdiv.id = "newDivId";
newdiv.className = "newsearch";
```

Finally, when removing the element, you're incorrectly referencing the parent as a property of the child (`newdiv.orgdiv.removeChild(newdiv);`). Instead, just access the parent directly:

```
orgdiv.removeChild(newdiv);
```

So your final solution becomes:

```
function ajxsrch(str) {
    var orgdiv = document.getElementById("search");
    var newdiv = document.getElementById("newDivId");

    if (str.length != 0) {
        if (count == 0) {
            newdiv = document.createElement('DIV');
            newdiv.id = "newDivId";
            newdiv.className = "newsearch";

            orgdiv.appendChild(newdiv);
            count = 1;
            alert("firstif");
        } else alert("first if else");
    } else {
        alert(str);
        count = 0;
        alert(count);
        orgdiv.removeChild(newdiv);
    }
}
```

See also [Node.removeChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.removeChild) MDN docs

Comment: Note that you can also reference an elements parent through the `parentNode` property. So you could also write `newdiv.parentNode.removeChild(newdiv)`. Notice that `parentNode` is the literal property name, not a placeholder.